# Текст накладывается друг на друга и выходит за рамки блока

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url("../images/pattern.png");
  font-family: Tahoma;
  line-height: 1.5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card-photo {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #098e00;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-photo" src="assec/images/man.jpg" alt="No name">
  <h1 class="card-title"> Сантехник </h1>
  <p>Текст выходитыфафыафышарфыаршфыхарфыхрахфырахфырахфырахфырахфыа</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Скопируйте кодом, чтобы мы смогли проверить и помочь.

Comment: Вставил код, спасибо за ранее

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была тут: `line-height: 1.5px;`. Вы указали `1.5px`, а это очень мало, вот и еффект как-будто текст сам на себя наложился.

Возможно, Вы хотели указать `line-height: 1.5`, `1.5` означает размер `1.5 * размер текущего шрифта font-size`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url("../images/pattern.png");
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.card-photo {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #098e00;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-photo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/VAN_CAT.png/1200px-VAN_CAT.png" alt="No name">
  <h1 class="card-title"> Сантехник </h1>
  <p>Текст выходитыфафыафышарфыаршфыхарфыхрахфырахфырахфырахфырахфыа</p>
</div>
```